# What to write in the Procfile?

Tags: java, heroku, procfile

What to write in the Procfile?

Im writing a web app using maven to make .war packaging.
It works on my localhost just fine when I use Tomcat to make Artifact filmography2:war exploded

However, when i want to deploy it in heroku, I have no idea what to write in the Procfile.
When I run heroku local web the error message is this

C:\Users\Alex\filmography2>heroku local web
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.39.1 to 7.39.2.
2:09:36 PM web.1 |  Unrecognized
2:09:36 PM web.1 |  option: -war
2:09:36 PM web.1 |  Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
2:09:36 PM web.1 |  Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
2:09:36 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null

My procfile looks like this

web: java -war C:\Users\Alex\filmography2\target\filmography2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

My project structure looks like this
[image: Project structure]
I follow this tutorial :   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java#the-procfile

Comment: When you open your command prompt. What command do you write to execute your project? In your Procfile you put `web: <command>`

Comment: Looks to me as if `$JAVA_OPTS` is not found or not resolved.

Comment: Im not using java opts -- edited question, please take another look  @TinNguyen

Answer (score 1):

The `Procfile` should contain the instruction to run your project.

This is a simple example: `web: java -jar path-to-my-project/target/my-project.jar`

The first part, `web` tells heroku which process type you are going to use.
The following part tells heroku how to run your project - in this case, a .jar.

How are you running it locally? Are you building a jar and running it?
How are you sending it to heroku? Are you 'uploading' a jar and running or sending your whole project/code to heroku?

They have a very good [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java) on their website about deploying java apps to heroku.

Comment: Im creating a .war in the target folder:


C:\Users\Alex\filmography2\target\filmography2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war .



 `web: java -war C:\Users\Alex\filmography2\target\filmography2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`Do you think I have set the path wrong ? should it just begin with target?



It gives the error of unrecognized -war option:           
`


C:\Users\Alex\filmography2>heroku local web
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.39.1 to 7.39.2.
2:09:36 PM web.1 |  Unrecognized
 option: -war
2:09:36 PM web.1 |  Error

Comment: The path should be a place where heroku knows about it since you are going to run it there. Your command is not quite right, it should be `java -jar path-to-your-project/your-file.war`. Can you try this command and see? Starting on your local environment until you make it run through command line is a good starting point.

Comment: should i add -jar even though im trying to run a .war file? and if im using spring mvc with a controller class, is this the main manifest attribute?

Comment: Well, it depends... it is quite hard to tell without knowing your project but I am assuming you have an embedded server inside that. If this is the case, running like that is fine. If not, you need to deploy your war file to an already running server! Regarding spring mvc and controllers, you still need a main class, one that will start your application. Are you using spring-boot? I would recommend following a simple spring tutorial in this case... by the end of that, you should have a running .jar with a correct main class and controllers!