# What exactly should the path to jar in Procfile be for spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, procfile

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to heroku.  (Also using a JawsDB MySQL addon).
After I push to git, and also to heroku (git push heroku mybranch:master), and build is always successful, I always get an error:

`at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"`

I gather this to mean my Procfile is incorrect. The file name is spelled correctly, it has no extension, and  I have stated there:

`web: java -jar C:/Users/Myname/Documents/Programming/appFolder/target/*.jar`

The above line shows up also in heroku.com/resources -> free Dynos.  So the Procfile contents do get picked up.

I searched SO and other places, and came across questions like [Heroku SprinBoot Deployment is sucess but Status is 503 Service Unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035291/heroku-sprinboot-deployment-is-sucess-but-status-is-503-service-unavailable) and [What to write in the Procfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006421/what-to-write-in-the-procfile) and others, but did not find a final and practical answer to my question.

My question is:

1.Which jar am I directing Heroku to?  Heroku itself builds the jar, and it does not appear in my appFolder/target.  Just some old jar I once manually built through the 'package' command in eclipse.  That's also why I wrote *.jar... (in my desperation,) I want him to collect **any** jar he finds, since I really don't know what the name of it is supposed to be...

And then what would the correct pattern be (back- or forward-slashes?  start from C:/?)

And to help me understand the background better:

2. Am I supposed to build the jar myself?  And if so, what good does Heroku's build do?
3. Where is Heroku's jar stored, if I want to access it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the ProcFile is fine otherwise it wouldn't build and deploy. You can try to scale up the Dyno `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a APP_NAME`, also check out https://github.com/gcatanese/JavaHerokuProcfile

Comment: @BeppeC I think that scaling definitely changed something.  Now instead of the 'heroku ps' command giving 'no Dynos' it gives 'web.1: crashed 2021/11/21 14:49:44 +0200 (~ 8s ago)'.  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I still remain with the question:  Why does heroku build the file and where does it store it?  Because it seems like I still need to refer to my locally-built jar file.

Comment: @BeppeC please add your scaling suggestion as an answer so that I can accept it, because that was basically the solution (and the path in the Procfile was target/jarName.jar where I made my own jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale up the Dyno formation

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 -a APP_NAME
```

Don't use the local path of the jar file but instead the path relative to the project as you push to Heroku:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/jarName.jar
```